# libGDX - Using different InputProcessors for different screens?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I don't understand how `InputProcessor` is supposed to work.

I have multiple `Screens` for a game. I created a `MyInputProcessor` `class` that `implements` InputProcessor. In my `MenuState class` I `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor` to an instance of the class.

1. First of all, how should I access and set variables that are defined in my `MainMenu class` in `MyInputProcessor`? If I want the `touchDown` method to change a variable for example.
2. If I switch `Screens`, do I have to create a new `InputProcessor class` to check for other touch events? I obviously don't want it to continue checking for things meant for `MainMenu class`. How am I supposed to use it?
3. Am I just supposed to create a whole new `InputProcessor` for each `Screen`?

I find this all very confusing. Thankful for any help at all.

Comment: Input is usually tightly coupled to each screen so a common pattern is to have each screen implement InputProcessor, then call Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this) in the screen's show() method. Basically, yes you'll need to define what to do with input on each screen. Using Stages is another possibility that you can choose to ignore for now. Stage also implements InputProcessor. Commonly, people use Stages for UI things (buttons, input).

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying. InputProcessor has confused the hell out of me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, usually you create one `InputProcessor` for every `Screen`, or even better for every object, that needs to process inputs. This object can be a `Screen`, but it can be a `Player` to.
So every object that needs to get notified about any input should implement `InputProcessor` and handle the relevant inputs.
Also make sure to set your `InputProcessor` as the current, active one (using `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor`).
The `Screen`s for example could set themself as the current `InputProcessor` in the `show` method (and eventually unregister themself in the `hide`).
IF you want to use multiple `InputProcessor`s at once (for example in the `GameScreen`, where the `Player` is controlled using "w,a,s,d", but you want to show a `PauseMenu` on "Esc"), just use `InputMultiplexer` and register every `InputProcessor` on that multiplexer.
If you use `InputMultiplexer`, make sure to take care about the return value of your `InputProcessor`-methods:
- Return `true`, if the proccessor handled the event (for example in the `Player`s `InputProcessor`, when "w", "a", "s" or "d" is pressed).
- Return `false`, when you did not handle the event (for example in the `Player`s `InputProcessor`, when "Esc" is pressed).
The `InputMulitplexer` will go through all it's `InputProcessor`s and send them the event, unitl one of them returns `true`. All others won't get notified about the event.
Also note, that `Stage` is an `InputProcessor`, which distributes the event to it's `Actor`s. So if you want to handle inputs in your `Actor`s, make sure to set `Stage` as you current `InputProcessor`.

Comment: Greatly appreciate your help. Would you suggest using stages when making basic mobile games with one touch handlat

Comment: Accidentally sent the above comment. Continuing from  "one": touch game play? Or is it overkill? I don't have any experience with it, should I have?

Comment: Well, `Stage` has some advantages but also some drawbacks. It is perfekt for any UI (like menus) and also smaller games.  
Stage already supports clicks/touches on `Actor`s, while without `Stage` you would have to search for the touched object yourself.
On the other hand `Stage` makes it [almost impossible using an MVC-pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21238638/using-mvc-with-libgdx-scene2d) which is pretty important for bigger games.
So I would definitely use `Stage` for UI and consider using it for smaller games. But take a look at it's documentation on the Libgdx wiki!

Comment: I definitely will. Thank you!

Comment: If you want to use `Stage`, you should read the [documentation](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d). Other experience is not needed, you always start new things without experience :) But ofc you should start small, maybe try to create menus before starting with the actualy gameplay?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `Stage` as your `InputProcessor`?
If yes I, assume you have separate `Stage` instance for every screen.

You should add `Actors` to the stage and let them handle the input.
If you want to combine more input processors you do this:

```
InputMultiplexer multiplexer = new InputMultiplexer();
multiplexer.addProcessor(yourCustomInputProcessor);
multiplexer.addProcessor(stage)
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(multiplexer);
```

**EDIT**
Don't call `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor` from constructor of the Main screen but rather in the moment when it appears.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will have to read up on this though as I am completely lost. Right now I just have a class implementing `InputProcessor` which I create an instance off when I change Screen checking if stuff is happening. I don't use stages as I've never encountered them before.

Comment: Stages are pretty good, you just create whatever Actor you like and call `stage.update()` and `stage.draw()` in draw method of your screen. `stage.update()` will call method `act()` on every actor it contains.

So when you are creating extending `Actor` you need to override those 2 methods.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will learn more about stages and actors.